# The pythonic way to handle sqlalchemy models

Tags: sqlalchemy, python

I'm working with sqlalchemy, and coming from learning an orm with ruby/rails activerecord and datamapper, it is a bit different.

So, having some models and needing what I think of as class and instance level methods, I see that python does not do this, or the level I understand of python so far does not do this. What is the pythonic way to build new methods for a model: decorators, make a module and import methods, etc? I need to various things so there is no specific coding question, just a general request for guidance on effective ways to handle models with sqlalchemy where model specific methods need to be handled.

Note: this is not an invitation to debate language specifics, I only mention what I've learned so far and how I can take this to application in a new situation.

Comment: Er, Python does have both classmethods and instancemethods. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Guidance in terms of pointing out tutorials or code examples I've missed or not found perhaps. I'm still in the middle of mostly rtfm, and thought I'd at least ask to get some pointers.

Comment: Done some basic setup using the declarative methods, added a few methods that just pass, lots of reading between the SQa docs and tutorial and the command line -- things to learn within a basic project. My question is just to get more input.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make model methods as class methods on a model definition. For example:

```
class User(object):

    @classmethod
    def get_by_username(cls, dbsession, username):
        return dbsession.query(cls).filter(cls.username==username).scalar()

mapper(User, tables.auth_user,
    properties={
        ...
        }
    )
```

Allows you to use the class as a container for table specific methods. Like this:

```
user = User.get_by_username(session, "me")
```

Comment: This is along the lines of what I haven't been able to do yet; basically getting the queries right and then wrapping them with a neat interface to the model.

Comment: This is a useful example, I'd like to take this and turn it into a 'get_by_*' function filter to prevent from writing 100 times for a model (just as an example and looking forward)